# Why templates mixed with isolation in ShadowDOM?

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom

The title is a bit illogical, but this is the shortest explanation of what will be discussed. Can anybody explain from architecture's point of view? Templates is just templates. Custom HTML elements is just custom elements. Isolation is just isolation. *Different strategies exist* for CSS styling in abstract area.

Many CSS frameworks uses "preflight" CSS code to normalize behavior for different browsers.. Utility-first CSS framework - Tailwind, generate the global CSS styling based on found CSS classes in the parsed sources. This is an example when isolation isn't needed. Sometimes developers use prefixes for CSS classes and so on. It's beautiful when the design elements of a large site are similar, so global styling is important and, by the way, reduces the code.

Imho isolation is a sweet thing, but when we can't use it separately, this **really limits** possible ways of using templates and custom elements. Good solution is when isolation is a separate thing, for example with element `<isolate>` or attribute.

Is it possible to use `<template>` with `<slot>` (and custom HTML elements) using global CSS styling? I'm trying to find a solution, but I cannot find and I don't understand existing architectural solution. Can anybody explain?

---

Thanks, Engelman. I found a solution if this is the fastest:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <style>
      .title { background: #77f; color: #fff; padding:10px }
      .desc { margin-left: 30px } .desc p { color: red }
      dt { font-size: 390% }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>MY-EL</h1>
    <template>
      <!--  for files just include common styles -->
      <style>@import url('common.css')</style>
      <span class="title"><slot name="title">DEFAULTS</slot></span>
      <div class="desc"><slot name="desc"><p>DEFAULTS</p></slot></div><hr>
    </template>
    <my-el>
      <dl slot="desc"><dt>390%</dt><dd>yyy</dd></dl>
    </my-el>
    <my-el>
      <span slot="title">zzz</span>
    </my-el>
    <script>
customElements.define('my-el',
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      const template = document.querySelector('template').content;
      const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
      shadow.appendChild(template.cloneNode(true));
      const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
      sheet.replace(document.querySelector('style').innerHTML);
      // for DEV (& may be PROD) posssible this way:
      shadow.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet];
    }
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, ``<slot>`` are tied to shadowDOM. You have to look into **constructable stylesheets**